# syntax help for using .Length with a string variable

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using multiple case statements/arrays although I am only posting 1 for clarity.

`typeSelected` is set from a `combobox.SelectedIndex` value and is used to select the case to run.

In the case I set a variable `typeUnits`, in the example, to the string `"lengthUnits"`, which is the name of the array with 3 items in.

I want the for loop to run using `lengthUnits.Length` but the code is processing this as `typeUnits.Length`, can someone please point me in the right direction?

I have tried `typeUnits.Text` `typeUnits.ToString()` `typeUnits.Content` but nothing works.

```
string[] lengthUnits = new string[] {"Feet", "Miles", "Inches"};

int typeSelected = cmb_Select_Type.SelectedIndex;

        switch (typeSelected)
        {
            case 1: typeUnits = "lengthUnits"; break; //Length Units
            default: break;
        }

            for (int i = 0; i < typeUnits.Length; i++)
            {
                cmb_Select_From.Items.Add(typeUnits[i]);
            }
```

If I can't get this to work then I need to write the for loop multiple times for each condition, I was trying to avoid that by just writing it once.

Comment: Please carefully read [MCVE] guidance and update your post accordingly. At the same time please remove all "new here", "don't downvote" and "thank you" text from your post as none of it adds any information about problem you have.

Comment: As I tried to make clear in my original post, I am not a programmer, I am new to all of this and I have no clue about the terminology, I was hoping to make that clear so that people didn't reply to me using language I didn't understand, but apparently thats not allowed here... So I got a few answers, but I don't understand them, whats the difference between a string and a string[] ? How can I ask for help if I can't make it clear what help I need? Is there another website I should perhaps use more suited to beginners? I would normally say thanks at this point but that seems to be forbidden.

Comment: Although most people won't do this (they would go to find a book and learn), I'm pretty sure you are free and welcome to ask "what's the difference between `string` and `string[]`". By the way, it's a pretty bad idea to step into complex technologies like WPF before you are familiar with C# itself.

Comment: I googled difference between string and string[] but it only explains string, looking up the string syntax does not explain anything about [] that I can understand. I have the microsoft developer step by step book but it's 2 inches thick and unless you know what you specifically need to look up, it would take a month to read it, assignment is due on monday, and I realise it's a bad idea, Im not doing this through choice, I got introduced to visual studio in january, shown an array and a for loop, and told to write an app, I need these credits to get in to uni next year, I am not a programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below just assigns the proper string[] to typeUnits. I added a second string[] called randomStringArray so you can see how it works with two cases.

```
        string[] lengthUnits = { "Feet", "Miles", "Inches" };
        string[] randomStringArray = { "Test", "this", "please" };
        string[] typeUnits;

        int typeSelected = cmb_Select_Type.SelectedIndex;

        switch (typeSelected)
        {
            case 1: typeUnits = lengthUnits;
                break; //Length Units

            case 2: typeUnits = randomStringArray;
                break;

            default: break;
        }

        if (typeUnits != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < typeUnits.Length; i++)
            {
                cmb_Select_From.Items.Add(typeUnits[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand it, but this is exactly what I needed, works perfecty.

Comment: Although I have been specifically told that saying thank you is forbidden, I would just like to say thanks for your help, I have read many other posts on here were people ask simple questions and say thanks without getting hammered by the admins, so I will just have to take my chances, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `typeUnits` seems to be declared as a string, since you assign it the value `"lengthUnits"`. When you then use `typeUnits.Length`, you get the length of the string (which is 11 in this case).

The variable `typeUnits` should be of type `string[]`, and assigned like this:

```
string[] typeUnits;

switch (typeSelected)
{
    case 1: typeUnits = lengthUnits; break; // No double quotes
    default: break;
}
```

Comment: indeed the string is assigned using  string typeUnits = ""; but what is the difference between a string and a string[ ] ?

Comment: In your code, you want the variable `typeUnits` to point to the list of units that corresponds to the selection made in `combobox`. Since your lists of units (like `lengthUnits`) are of type `string[]`, the variable `typeUnits` should be of the same type. The type `string` is a single string of characters (like `"Hello world!"`), while `string[]` is an array of strings of characters. For example, `lengthUnits` is an array containing 3 strings of characters.

Comment: I would really like to say thanks for trying to explain this to me, but according to the post at the top by Alexei Levenkov, saying thanks to someone is fobidden here, so instead I shall buy you a beer and drink it for you, you enjoyed it very much! I had no idea this web site was going to be so elitist or I would never have come here for help in the first place.. As it stands I am still stuck with this project and Im not sure I can post on here any more to ask another question without getting hammered by the coding elite that seem to admin this place, but thanks anyway for trying to help.

Comment: @UnhandledException I hope you will keep asking questions here. I know that the moderators here are quite strict on keeping the content conform to the SO rules, and some of them can express it more bluntly than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk about your approach first. You are trying to access a variable with a string representing its name. This is only possible if that variable is a member, which you can do it with the power of reflection. If the variable is local, reflection can't help you neither.

However, by all means it shouldn't be a problem in this specific snippet of code. Why must lengthUnits be a string? Can't it be of type string[]? If it is an array of strings, just like lengthUnits, you can assign lengthUnits to it directly, and enumerate lengthUnits directly.

If there is a special reason lengthUnits must be a string, you can still use a Dictionary to map a name to its actual value. Since your question didn't reflect why you are doing this, I'm not going into detail with it for now.

Comment: I don't understand a word of this, member of what? reflection? I don't know how a string differs from a string[ ] and I don't understand Dictionary map a name to its actual value, I am not a programmer and I don't understand the terminology.